# How to increase my score gradually with a timer?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently creating a hidden object game and I have been stuck on how to add a timer and countdown to my game. I have currently a score which generates after all of the objects have been clicked however I would love if the score went up gradually once the user clicked on each one. here is my code below so far.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class trackingclicks : MonoBehaviour {

    //static variable added to count users clicks
    public static int totalclicks=0;
    //"mouseclick" keycode variable to look for mouse click
    public KeyCode mouseclick;

    public Transform scoreObj;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
    //checks the change in time, aka how much time has passed- bonus time starts at 90
        clickcontrol.timeBonus -= Time.deltaTime;

        if (clickcontrol.remainItems == 0) 
        {
            clickcontrol.totalScore += (70 + (Mathf.RoundToInt(clickcontrol.timeBonus)));
            scoreObj.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = "Score : " + clickcontrol.totalScore;
            clickcontrol.remainItems = -1;

        }
    //Check for mouse click
        if (Input.GetKeyDown (mouseclick)) 
        {
            totalclicks += 1;

        }

        if (totalclicks >= 5) 
        {
            Debug.Log ("FAIL!!!");
            totalclicks = 0;

        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Hey, please post your code here, in your question. And definitely not as an image file. That way people are not able to copy/past and test it. And therefore you won't get any answers ;-) Just copy/past your code in the question editor, select it and mark it as code with one of the buttons.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you just want to add to the score each time the player clicks on an object?

Comment: that title is so misleading. It is just postponing the closing of the question since it is about timer and counting clicks and has many answers already.

Comment: @ḞḹáḿíṅḡⱫỏḿƀíé yes sorry, that is exactly what I am trying to achieve however since its my first time using C# I am having some trouble achieving this.

Comment: Doing `scoreObj.GetComponent<TextMesh>()` every update is wasteful, do it once in `Awake()` or `Start()` and assign it to a `private TextMesh textMesh;`, the when you want to use it you do `textMesh.text = "Score : " + clickcontrol.totalScore;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use coroutines for timers (coroutines execute code after a certain amount of time). If you want your score to increment gradually once the player clicks on an object (I think that's what you're asking), then something like this should work:

```
public int score;

IEnumerator IncrementScore(int amount, int interval) { //amount is the amount of score to add over the time, interval is the time IN SECONDS between adds
    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(interval);
    score++;
    }

}
```

I wasn't sure where the score variable was so I made a new one; you can set it to your own, wherever it is. If you need more help, feel free to ask.